# Reading BMP file into an array

Tags: c++

I am writing a longer program and I found myself needing to read a .bmp file into an array in a specific way so that the rest of the program can use it without extensive rewrites. I failed to find older answers that would resolve my problem, and I am pretty much at the beginner stages.

The image I am trying to read is used to create a text font, so I want to read it character by character into an array, where the pixels belonging to one character are added in order to a 2d bool (true if pixel is not black) array [character_id] [pixel_n]. The dimensions of characters are predetermined and known, and the file is cropped so that they all appear in a single row with no unaccounted margins.

This is the [specific file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbjb0.png) I am trying to read, though here it might not show up as .bmp
As an example, [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TXKv.png), I want to read the pixels in the order of the yellow line, then jump to another character. For clarity each character is 5px wide and 11px high, with 1px of margin on both sides horizontally.

Based on what I was able to find, I have written a function to do it, but I fail to make it work as intended, as far as I can tell even the pixel values are not being read correctly:

```
void readBMP(char* filename)
{
    int i;
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];

    // read the 54-byte header
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    // number of pixels in total
    int size = 3 * width * height;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];
    // number of characters to read
    int counter1 = size / ((font_width + 2) * font_height) / 3 ;

    // read the rest of the data at once
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);
    fclose(f);

    //loop that goes from character to character
    for(int i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        //loop that reads one character into font_ref array
        for(int j = 0; j < font_height; j++)
        {
            //loop for each row of a character
            for(int k = 0; k < font_width; k++)
            {
                int w = static_cast<int>(data[3*(j*(font_width+2)*(counter1) + i*(font_width + 2) + 1 + k + j*font_width + j)-1]);

                if( w != 0 )
                    font_ref [i][(tmp)] = 1;
                else
                    font_ref [i][(tmp)] = 0;

                tmp++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`bool font_ref [150][font_width*font_height];` is the array where the font is being loaded and stored)

this code reads *something*, but the result is a seemingly random mess and I am unable to resolve that. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPJz.png) is an example of lowercase alphabet printed using another function in the program, where white pixels represent true bools. I am aware that some libraries exist to work with graphical files, however in this program I wanted to possibly avoid that to learn more lower-level things, and the goal is rather limited and specific.

Thank you in advance for any help with the issue.

Comment: Windows bitmap files have a padding

Comment: I am however not quite sure how it works, this is the first time I am working with graphical files. Does this functionally equal to assuming 4 bytes per pixel instead of 3?

Comment: _"I failed to find older answers that would resolve my problem"_.  [How long did you look?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196084/read-and-write-bmp-file-in-c)

Comment: For a better part of today, I in fact found that exact answer but I failed to understand it. As I said I am very much at a beginner stage.

Comment: Did you care to look at the link?

Comment: May I suggest using the [official Windows headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85)) instead of your own custom data types for this.

Comment: I suggest that your use your toolchain's debugger to step the code and ensure at each step the intended indexes are being calculated.  To facilitate that you might want to simplify some expressions by assigning sub-expressions to intermediate variables.  I'd also suggest better variable naming.  For example if you used `character_index` rather the `i` or `row` instead of `j`, your code would be easier to follow and your comments could be more succinct.  On the other hand most beginners post uncommented or poorly commented code, so I am being somewhat picky.

Comment: First you need to look at the header and verify that everything is as you expect it to be. For example, the offset to the pixel data is 54, the number of bits-per-pixel is 24, the compression type is BI_RGB (i.e. 0), the height is a positive number (if not, negate it). Assuming all that checks out, the pixels are stored as 3 bytes per pixel. However, each line of the image must have a multiple of 4 bytes. So there could be 1, 2, or 3 bytes of padding at the end of each line. The affects how much memory is needed for the buffer, as well as how you access the pixels in the buffer.

Comment: `int width = *(int*)&info[18];` is UB when `int` alignment is more than 2,  `memcpy()` is an alternative.

Comment: Endian issues may apply.  The .bmp file may use a different endian than the processor.

Comment: Kubackiewicz, report height and width found, before reading pixel data.  Is it 11 x 573?

Comment: `font_width, font_height` not defined.  `size = 3 * width * height` is wrong.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Kubackiewicz -- There are thousands of code examples of reading a BMP using C++ with and without using the Windows API.  Why not look at, run, and copy *working* examples, instead of fighting with trying to get something to work from scratch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The main errors are in the offset computation for a pixel in the bitmap data:

```
int w = static_cast<int>(data[3*(j*(font_width+2)*(counter1) + i*(font_width + 2) + 1 + k + j*font_width + j)-1]);
```

- `j*(font_width+2)*(counter1)` - This doesn't take into account that

  1. although you say *the file is cropped*, there is extra black space to the right of the last character cell, so the true `width` must be used;
  2. (as drescherjm and user3386109 mentioned) padding bytes are appended to the rows so that their length is a multiple of four bytes.
- `+ j*font_width + j)-1` - This part makes no sense - perhaps you tried to compensate the above errors.

This would be correct:

```
int w = data[j*(3*width+3&~3)+3*(i*(font_width+2)+1+k)];
```